# Qt 6 Resource Not Found

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qt6

I am using Qt6 and Cmake in which i have added a resource file.
I'm facing problem that the resource file is not found.

Following is the Cmake file in which i have added resource.qrc -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(bounce_ball VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)


qt_add_executable(appbounce_ball
    main.cpp
    resource.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(appbounce_ball
    URI bounce_ball
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml resource.qrc
    RESOURCES resource.qrc
)

set_target_properties(appbounce_ball PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appbounce_ball
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS appbounce_ball
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

this is the folder structure  in the image-

[image: Proj Folder]

```
Error -
qrc:/qt_resource/Main.qml:9:5: QML Image: Cannot open: 
qrc:/qt_resource/images/soccerball.png

Expecting to read the resource image file.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
qt_add_resources(IMAGE_RESOURCES images.qrc)
```

to your CMAKE file. To use this you need the Core component from QT as well:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
```

Then change the following target to:

```
qt_add_executable(appbounce_ball
    main.cpp
    ${IMAGE_RESOURCES}
)
```

Now you should be able to address your images by e.g. `source: "qrc:/images/soccerball.png"`

Comment: I'm using Qt Quick not Core. Is it required to add?

Comment: qt_add_resources is defined in Core, so I guess you have to add it. You can try it out, CMAKE will tell you if it is working or not...

Comment: It is still not working with the changes. Is the problem because of this warning for qt policy QTP0001?

Comment: Have you changed your link to qrc:/images/soccerball.png without qt_resource?

Comment: and add qt_policy(SET QTP0001 NEW)

Comment: when i set qt_policy(SET QTP0001 NEW) it gives error - qrc:/testT/Main.qml: No such file or directory
and if set to OLD it is not able to find the resource file

Comment: Your main.qml is then in "qrc:/qt/qml/testT/Main.qml"

Comment: With qmake it is working fine. is it some configuration i need to do with cmake? 
Also working correctly on Qt 5.15 configuration with cmake. Is it a bug with Qt 6.2 and above?